# Can we store and share corel draw data on git?

Tags: git, coreldraw

My friends and I are working on a corel draw project, and like our other coding projects, we want to store and share our corel draw project on git. How can we set that up?

Comment: making a repo for corel draw files is the be the same as code files.  Git doesn't care what kind if files it is tracking, except that binary files may take up more room

Answer (score 2):

Corel draw files are binary files.  So you can share them like binary files.

Now, if you want to do *more* than just blobs, you could unpack the files and store the unpacked files and reconstruct.  This may require writing your own custom tools, so it isn't going to be for the faint of heart.

I will describe roughly what you could do.  If you aren't a reasonably skilled programmer *and* willing to experiment, I would advise against doing this.

Also, you might want to keep the original files around, in case this process somehow causes some kind of archive corruption.  This level of poking around in the innards of draw files is, obviously, unsupported.

---

Their internal structure is that of a zip archive with a few tweaks.  So you could unzip them and share the contents.  Much of their structure is still in a few binary blobs, but more structure will be available for git to get its claws into.  It might help.

If you want to reconstruct them from the unzipped set of files, you must ensure that the "mimetype" file is the first file in the archive, and it is not compressed when put in the zip archive.  (This means that the mimetype is stored in plain text in the resulting zip file at a known offset)

There may be additional requirements on what kind of compression settings you have to use, I don't recall right now.  In general, be careful about messing with the internal contents of the archive, as draw might not like what you did to it and fail.